# smart way of defining a table

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

This is possibly a dumb question: inside a function, I first define

```
Rho = Table[xrho[m], {m, 1, k}]
```

then populate it using

```
Do[xrho[d] = q1^i q2^j; d++, {i, 1, Length[p]}, {j, 1, Length[p[[i]]]}]
```

and then update its value such that I can call it later inside the function

```
RhoTrue = Table[xrho[m], {m, 1, k}]
```

This works but seems dumb: is there a way to directly define it in therms of the other two (or more) counting variables?

Comment: you may want to have a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/57 (third bullet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sue what you're trying to do, but would the single line

```
RhoTrue = Flatten[Table[q1^i q2^j, {i, 1, Length[p]}, {j, 1, Length[p[[i]]]}]]
```

not work for you?

Comment: thanks, indeed it works; I said it was a dumb question :)